# Loop with cummulative substitution

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am new to R, and muddling through my first loops, so please bear with me.

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
VarName Value
Var1a   1
Var1b   3
Var2a   5
Var2b   4
Var3a   7
Var3b   6
CoeffVar1   0.55
CoeffVar2   0.75
CoeffVar3   -2.15
```

It contains variables and coefficients. I would like to apply the coefficients to these variables AND substitute the “a variables” for “b variables” cumulatively.  For instance:

Estimation0 would use 3 “a variables” (Var1a,Var2a and Var3a) and zero “b variables”.

```
Estimation0  = Var1a*Coefficient1 + Var2a*Coefficient2 + Var3a*Coefficient3 = -10.75
```

What I would like to do is to progressively substitute Var1-3 for Var1-3b and save each estimation. In this case:

```
Estimation1 = Var1b*Coefficient1 + Var2a*Coefficient2 + Var3a*Coefficient3 = -9.65
Estimation2 = Var1b*Coefficient1 + Var2b*Coefficient2 + Var3a*Coefficient3 = -10.4
Estimation3 = Var1b*Coefficient1 + Var2b*Coefficient2 + Var3b*Coefficient3 = -8.25
```

Do you know how could it be done?

I am a bit lost so any piece of advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see anything "cummulative"  about your problem?

Comment: Thanks Roland for the answer. I saw the change from "a Variables" to "b variables" as being a cumulative process. 
In your code you calculate all combinations, but now I am thinking about how to pick only the ones I am interested in. The distance between relevant estimations follows a Fibonacci sequence, so I guess the for loop is unavoidable. Is that right? Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="VarName Value
Var1a   1
Var1b   3
Var2a   5
Var2b   4
Var3a   7
Var3b   6
CoeffVar1   0.55
CoeffVar2   0.75
CoeffVar3   -2.15", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#reorganize data
mat <- matrix(DF$Value[1:6], nrow=2)
coef <- DF$Value[7:9]

#all combinations
var <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), function(j) mat[,j])) )
#      Var1 Var2 Var3
# [1,]    1    5    7
# [2,]    3    5    7
# [3,]    1    4    7
# [4,]    3    4    7
# [5,]    1    5    6
# [6,]    3    5    6
# [7,]    1    4    6
# [8,]    3    4    6

#a bit of matrix algebra
var %*% coef
#        [,1]
# [1,] -10.75
# [2,]  -9.65
# [3,] -11.50
# [4,] -10.40
# [5,]  -8.60
# [6,]  -7.50
# [7,]  -9.35
# [8,]  -8.25
```